# Nginx reverse proxy forces 301 on subdomain (and it shouldn't)

Tags: nginx, ssl, rewrite, subdomain

So I'm using Nginx (1.4.3) to reverse proxy a domain and sub-domains. I installed SSL certs to handle the main domain (example.com) and a couple sub-domains (lets say test.example.com and mail.example.com). So I naturally used a 301 return to move http requests to https.

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Works great. But if I introduce another sub-domain that I don't want under the HTTPS SSL Certs (because I don't have a wildcard cert and don't need it for this subdomain). Nginx still seems to apply the 301 to it, even though the `server_name` has been implicitly set. Since it's 1.4.3 I've split them up in the `conf.d` folder.

I figure it is doing this because if I clear my browser cache, and navigate to the new sub domain (sd.example.com) it works fine and doesn't rewrite to https. But then if I go to the main site (example.com) the rewrite kicks in, I get sent to https://example.com, and no problems there. But then, if I try and go back to sd.example.com, I get rewritten to https://sd.example.com and the big red chrome error pops up.

Any ideas why this is happening? I'd prefer to stop banging my head around on this one.

Comment: Did you set secure cookies or HSTS?

Comment: That was quick. No to the secure cookies, but there is a HSTS I noticed. Never thought of that, would that do it?

Comment: Well that was dumb of me. The HSTS did include the `includeSubDomains` directive. I comment it out and it works now. HSTS is new to me so I forgot about it.

Answer (score 2):

*posted answers from OP comment*

The problem was caused by HSTS header. In main domain, there is entry [`includeSubDomains` in HSTS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Excessively_Strict_STS) header . If a browser visits main domain and receive that HSTS header, the browser will force to connect via HTTPS in **main domain and subdomain too**. So, its pretty clear that nginx doesn't cause the redirection.

If you don't want subdomain use HTTPS, the solution is remove `includeSubDomains` in HSTS header.